# Custom UITextField with arrow to the right

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have `UITextField` which are displaying `SpinnerView`, so I want to customize them by adding an arrow pointing to the bottom on the right side, how to do? I was thinking about adding an `UIImageView` to the right but I wan't to know if they're an another solution.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("updatePicker"), name: UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)

let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 400))

//        pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self
self.pickerView = pickerView

tfProjet.inputView = pickerView
```

Comment: How are spinners relevant, do you want to replace them ? Show your code so that the others could understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @A-Live Look my edit please, but I think it's just about storyboard I have to "customize" UITextField

Comment: Still don't see any spinners.

Comment: @A-Live I do an input view of a spinner on my textfield, and so that's why I want to show a arrow on the right of the textfield to tell that's it's a spinner

Comment: Ah, you mean a `UIPickerView`, not a spinner. Check the documentation of `UITextView`, it has a property to display a view on the right side.